# Multiple types in query string in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, parsing, request.querystring

I am creating a get api in nodejs.I am requesting the following url

> http://localhost:8080/api?id=20&condition1=true&arr=[{prop1:1}]&obj={a:1,b:2}
>   And I am getting the request query object as follows-

```
req.query = {
   arr:"[{prop1:1}]",
   condition1:"true",
   id:"20",
  obj:"{a:1,b:2}" 
}
```

I want to convert the query object keys to appropriate types.My query object should be converted to

```
req.query = {
       arr:[{prop1:1}], // Array
       condition1:true, // Boolean
       id:20, // Number
      obj: {a:1,b:2} //Object
    }
```

req.query object is dynamic, it can contain any number of objects, array, boolean , number or strings. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Your key value will be comma separated, right? Like `req.query = {
   arr:"[{prop1:1}]",
   condition1:"true",
   id:"20",
  obj:"{a:1,b:2}" ,
}`

Comment: Yes @ShamsNahid. Thank you for suggesting edit. Could you please help me with this problem

Comment: Let me try. Of course, someone will help you out.

Comment: why not simply use a post request?

Comment: @Praveen      Because this is supposed to be a get request , I am using query object to filter out the result.

Comment: why does it have to be get request? This kind of data are supposed to be sent in request body. btw, you can use javascript's eval method, parseInt, JSON.parse.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality doesn't come out of the box with `express` and query parameters.

The problem is that in order for the query string parser to know if `"true"` is actual boolean `true` or the string `"true"` it needs some sort of `Schema` for the query object to help parsing the string.

**Option A**

What I can recommend is using [Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi).

In your case it will look like :

```
const Joi = require( "joi" );


const querySchema = {
    arr: Joi.array(),
    condition1: Joi.boolean(),
    id: Joi.number(),
    obj: {
      a: Joi.number(),
      b: Joi.number()
    }
}
```

Having this schema you can attach it to your express method and use [`Joi.validate`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v14.3.0/API.md#validatevalue-schema-options-callback) To validate it.

```
function getFoo( req, res, next ) {
    const query = req.query; // query is { condition1: "true" // string, ... }
    Joi.validate( query, querySchema, ( err, values ) => {
        values.condition1 === true // converted to boolean
    } );
}
```

**Option B**

Another way of having properly typed GET requests would be to trick the query parameters and just provide a stringified JSON.

```
GET localhost/foo?data='{"foo":true,"bar":1}'
```

This will give you the possibility to just parse the request query

```
function getFoo( req, res, next ) {
    const data = JSON.parse( req.query.data )
    data.foo // boolean
    data.bar // number
}
```

Comment: the query string will be dynamic i.e. i don't know which query param will be array or object or boolean. Could you suggest some package for this problem.
And I can't use option B because JSON.parse will give error in case of string

Comment: You can use `try { const data = JSON.parse( req.query.data ) } catch ( error ) { // Not JSON }`. This will catch the error of JSON.parse

Comment: Option B could be better.